# correlation outcome does not table but _

Tags: python

When I get the result of correlation, the outcome is _ .
How can I get the correlation table?

```
train_num = ['person_attribute_a',
       'person_attribute_a_1', 'person_attribute_b', 'person_prefer_c',
       'person_prefer_d_1', 'person_prefer_d_2', 'person_prefer_d_3',
       'person_prefer_e', 'person_prefer_f', 'person_prefer_g',
       'person_prefer_h_1', 'person_prefer_h_2', 'person_prefer_h_3',
       'contents_attribute_i', 'contents_attribute_a',
       'contents_attribute_j_1', 'contents_attribute_j',
       'contents_attribute_c', 'contents_attribute_k', 'contents_attribute_l',
       'contents_attribute_d', 'contents_attribute_m', 'contents_attribute_e',
       'contents_attribute_h', 'person_rn', 'contents_rn','target']
train_num_df = pd.DataFrame(train_num)
print(train_num_df)

train_num_df.corr()
```

[image]

Comment: Correlation has meaning between two columns (two sets of values), your are trying to get correlation of single string column, which will not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

There should be numeric columns in dataframe

a simple example for your data

```
import pandas as pd

train_num = [('person_attribute_a',10,40),
       ('person_attribute_a_1',20,30), ('person_attribute_b',30,20), ('person_prefer_c',40,10)]
train_num_df = pd.DataFrame(train_num)
print(train_num_df)

print(train_num_df.corr())
```

Comment: 'person_attribute_a', 'person_attribute_a_1', 'person_attribute_b', 'person_prefer_c',
       'person_prefer_d_1', 'person_prefer_d_2', 'person_prefer_d_3' ..... these are column name and contain numeric values.

Comment: Ok, Then the problem is with  the dataframe you created.  Assign values properly to the train_num, then you get to to see corr as expected